# Amount of ways N can be written as sum of two or more non-repeating integers

Tags: algorithms

For example, 5 can be written in 2 ways:

- 4 + 1
- 3 + 2

8 can be written in 5 ways:

- 7+1
- 6+2
- 5+3
- 5+2+1
- 4+3+1

How could this be determined for any positive integer N?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known as the [number of strict partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)#Strict_partition_function).  Wikipedia contains a number of results on this.  You can compute the number using [dynamic programming](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info).